# Expected Array Error when calling Year() function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Edit 2: THIS HAS BEEN RESOLVED. I made the mistake of declaring a variable with the name 'Year'...

I am trying to get a cell to contain a copyright in a series of reports I deliver, and since the copyright changes with the year, I want to call the Year function to give me the current year so I don't have to update the macro every January. My code in question looks like this:

```
With .Cells(5, 1)
            .Value = Chr(169) & " " & Year(Date) & " NCH Marketing Services, Inc"
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 11
        End With
```

When I execute this code, I get the error message "Compile Error: Expected Array". The odd thing is, I have tried to run this macro on three separate occasions, and it did not compile the first or third times, but the second time, it ran just fine. I have not made any edits to the code, and I have looked online for syntax/usage of the Year function, and I cannot figure out why this is working sometimes. Is there a way I can implement this in a more reliable fashion?

Edit: Below is the full code

```
Option Explicit
Sub RGA_Format_Reports()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Year As Integer
Dim Quarter As Integer

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook

Dim iRows As Integer
Dim iCols As Integer

Dim shpTitle As Shape
Dim shpLogo As Shape


'Quarter = InputBox("Please enter the quarter number for which the reports are being run.")

'Year = InputBox("Please enter the year for which the reports are being run.")

'FolderPath = "G:\Analytical Services\Internal Client Requests\NRS\Scheduled\" & Year & "\Quarterly RGA Store Alert Reports\" & Year & " Q" & Quarter & "\"

'FolderPath = "G:\Analytical Services\General Team Folders\Kyle\Macro Tests\RGA Reports\"

'FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

'DoWhile FileName <> ""

    'Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        'With WorkBk

With ActiveWorkbook

        With .ActiveSheet

            iRows = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            iCols = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

            .Rows.AutoFit
            .Columns.AutoFit

            .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 30


            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
            .Range("A9").Select
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

            With .Range(.Cells(iRows - 2, 1), .Cells(iRows, 1))
                .WrapText = False
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Font.Size = 10
            End With


            With .PageSetup
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .CenterHorizontally = True
                .Zoom = False
                .Orientation = xlLandscape
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = False
                .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$8"
            End With


            .Range(.Cells(9, 3), .Cells(iRows, 3)).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .Range(.Cells(iRows - 4, 1), .Cells(iRows - 4, iCols)).Font.Bold = True
            .Range(.Cells(iRows - 4, 1), .Cells(iRows - 4, iCols)).Interior.Color = RGB(238, 236, 225)


            With .Range(.Cells(7, 9), .Cells(7, 12))
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Interior.Color = RGB(238, 236, 225)

                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                .Value = "Total Billed"
            End With


            With .Range(.Cells(7, 13), .Cells(7, 19))
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Interior.Color = RGB(238, 236, 225)

                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                .Value = "Total Adjustments"
            End With


            With .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(iRows - 4, 8))
                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            End With


            With .Range(.Cells(7, 9), .Cells(iRows - 4, 12))
                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            End With


            With .Range(.Cells(7, 13), .Cells(iRows - 4, 19))
                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

                With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

            End With

            If .Cells(9, 4) = 0 Then
                Columns("D:E").Delete
            End If

            For iRows = 1 To 4
                .Cells(iRows, 1).Font.Bold = True
                .Cells(iRows, 1).Font.Name = "Arial"
                If iRows = 1 Then
                    .Cells(iRows, 1).Font.Size = 14
                Else
                    .Cells(iRows, 1).Font.Size = 12
                End If
            Next iRows

            With .Cells(5, 1)
                .Value = Chr(169) & " " & Year(Date) & " NCH Marketing Services, Inc"
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Font.Size = 11
            End With

            .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 200

            .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1)).WrapText = False

            .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1)).Copy
            .Range("B1").Select
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            .Pictures.Paste.Select
            .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1)).ClearContents
            .Columns("A").AutoFit
            .Range("A1").Select

            Set shpTitle = .Shapes("Picture 1")
            With shpTitle
                .Name = "Title Picture"
                .Placement = xlFreeFloating
            End With

            Set shpLogo = .Shapes.AddPicture("G:\Analytical Services\AS Tools\AS Templates\NCH Logo.png", False, True, 1, 1, 60, 67)
            With shpLogo
                .Name = "Logo Picture"
                .Placement = xlFreeFloating
            End With

            With shpTitle
                .Left = 67
            End With


            .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 30



        End With

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: what is the reference to `With .Cells(5, 1)` ? what is the previous `With` you have in your code ? Otherwise, if you use `With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 1)` for instance, it works fine

Comment: the full chain is:

`With ActiveWorkbook
       With .ActiveSheet
              With .Cells(5,1)`

Comment: I'm skeptical that you didn't make any inadvertent changes to the code. Compile errors don't change dynamically. It would help if you gave more context. The answer almost certainly lies with code that you haven't shown.

Comment: @KPekosh coding tip, try allways setting your `Worksheet` objects. Like `Dim Sht as Worksheet`, the set it `Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` , and then just use `With Sht.Cells(5, 1)`

Comment: By no means an answer, but maybe this can help you pinpoint the problem: **i.** can you rule out any typos in variable names (did you use `Option Explicit`)  **ii.** is there any chance there's a problem with `.Cells(5, 1)` (not assigned to a specific worksheet in a specific workbook, like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 1)`

Comment: Look at your 4th line, you are using `Year` as your variable, `Dim Year As Integer`

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you, I know I should be doing that. I actually have commented out code in that allows this macro to loop through a multitude of these reports, and in that code I have set my Workbook and will be using .Sheets(1), but I have this current setup to test the code and see if I can get the actual meat of the macro to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ShaiRado pointed out that I had set a variable with the name of 'Year'. I am aware that declaring variables with the same name as functions is a big no no; I just had a mental lapse. Changing the variable declaration fixed my problem. Thanks @ShaiRado.

Comment: In your defense: VBA should never have you declare a variable with the same name a system function. Certainly not with Option Explicit.